# Blank() causes an error in an if() - PowerApps

Tags: if-statement, filter, powerapps

I am trying to filter a table from Dynamics 365 by selecting a radio button which will update the table on the screen.

The user has three options to choose from: "School", "Business", "All".

When the user selects "All" then it should look in the "Accounts" table and search the "industrycode" column for blank values.

Below is a working Filter(), which returns the result I want

```
Filter(Accounts,industrycode = Blank())
```

However if I add an If() statement to it determine which value the user selected from the radio, I get an error that says the '=' symbol is an invalid argument type.

```
Filter(Accounts,industrycode = If("All" in radio_cust_type.Selected.Value,Blank()))
```

EDIT: When I want to check for a "School", I use a filter like:

```
Filter(Accounts,industrycode=If("School" in radio_cust_type.Selected.Value,34))
```

I intend to combine the two filters later but right now I want to check for blanks

Comment: What do you want to display if the user selects "School" or "Business"?

Comment: industrycode is an integer in Dynamics 365 so when a user selects "School" then the result would be "34" and the filter for that is 'Filter(Accounts,industrycode=If("School" in radio_cust_type.Selected.Value,34))'. But at the moment "Business" industrycodes are empty in Dynamics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
If(
radio_cust_type.Selected.Value="All", Filter(Accounts, industrycode = Blank()),
radio_cust_type.Selected.Value="School", Filter(Accounts, industrycode = 34),
radio_cust_type.Selected.Value="Business", Filter(Accounts, industrycode = XX)
)
```

Where XX is the industry code for "Business"